# global counter in Django Application?

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if there is "global counter" in Django application, like the way I store "global counter" in Servlet Context scope in Tomcat.

something like

getServletContext().getAttribute("counter");
 counter++;

Comment: For those of us who don't know what a "global counter in Servlet Context scope in Tomcat" is, could you elaborate a little more on what functionality you'd like?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I added """getServletContext().getAttribute("counter"); counter++; """ to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a django application (or any wsgi application, for that matter), you don't know beforehand if your application will end up running standalone on a single server, or multithreaded, or multiprocessed, or even in multiple separate machines as part of a load balancing strategy.

If you're going to make the constraint "*my application only works on single-process servers*" then you can use something like this:

```
from django import settings
settings.counter += 1
```

However that constraint is often not feasible. So you must use external storage to your counter.

If you want to keep it on memory, maybe a memcached

Maybe you just log the requests to this view. So when you want the counter just count the number of entries in the log.

The log could be file-based, or it could be a table in the database, just define a new model on your `models.py`.

Comment: Thanks, If I have another application accessing this counter, will it automatically be updated ? 

Say counter = 0  in settings.py,  in webpage1.py counter += 1, when I import this counter in other application, it equals 0 or 1 ?

Comment: It seems I have to use  models.py to save the counter in database, I'm not sure if there is other better way.

Comment: if you do "settings.counter += 1" then it will be updated for the current process.